# Can't bring content_id through to list of collection and then add to a collection ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

SO STUCK! Need helps on this Rails App.

For content, index and show content needs to be available to everyone. Content can be in collections, which are private.

I have the privacy set up through devise, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to connect a content_id to many different collection_ids. The flow would be:

Click content on homepage

Click goes to a list of collections to potentially add the content to

Click the button on a collection to add the content [ THIS IS WHERE I KEEP GETTING STUCK ]

When I click into a collection, I can view all of the contents within the collection and delete the content if I no longer want it there.

I've looked at everything from has_and_belongs_to_many models, nested forms, etc. but nothing seems to bring through the content_id.

Also note, the main view is home/index.html.erb.

```
    routes.rb
      resources :contents
      resources :collections
      resources :collections_contents

    collection model
      has_many :collections_contents, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :contents, :through => :collections_contents

    content model
      has_many :collections_contents
      has_many :collections, :through => :collections_contents

    collections_content model
      belongs_to :content
      belongs_to :collection


    Collection and content controllers are the normal scaffold.

    Collections_contents_controller

    def create
      @collection = current_collection
      content = Content.find(params[:content_id])
      @collections_content = @collection.collection_content.build
      @collections_content.content = content

    respond_to do |format|
    if @collections_content.save
       format.html { redirect_to @collections_content.collection, notice: 'Collections content was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @collections_content, status: :created, location: @collections_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @collections_content.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end



    home/index.html.erb
<%  if user_signed_in? %>
  <table>
      <% @collections.each do |collection| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= collection.name %></td>
          <td><%= collection.thumbnail %></td>
          <td><%= collection.content_number %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'View Collection', collection %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Create New Collection', new_collection_path %>
<table>
  <% @contents.each do |content| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= content.title %></td>
      <td><%= content.short_description %></td>
      <td><%= content.published_date %></td>
      <td><%= content.image %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Read More', content %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Add Content to Collection', collections_path(content_id: content) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>


    <% @collections.each do |collection| %>
      <tr>
       <td><%= collection.name %></td>
       <td><%= collection.thumbnail %></td>
       <td><%= collection.content_number %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Add to Collection' %></td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: Why [ask the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470696/adding-contents-to-a-collections-cant-pull-in-content-id-correctly-rails)?

Comment: I added code this time.

Comment: You can edit the original question. I suggest you spend some time reading the [help]

Answer (score 0):

There is a RailsCast on how to properly do this :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Hope it helps someone out there!